# Onfileloaded event not called when file is opened from Drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to open a file in my Google Drive which was created by my Google Realtime application.  Although the URL opens correctly, the onfileloaded event is not fired following the afterAuth event.  Should I expect and handle a different event in my application when the file created by it is opened from Google Drive.  Copying the URL in a different window fires the onfileload event.

OnfileLoaded:

```
function onFileLoaded(doc) {
  Util.log.console("Doc:");
  Util.log.console(doc);
  data = doc.getModel().getRoot().get('data');
}
```

I also tried handling the onLoad (of model) event.  Didn't help either.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet showing how you are configuring the onfileloaded event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Parses the hash parameters to this page and returns them as an object.
 * @function
 */
rtclient.getParams = function() {
  var params = {};
  // The following statement was changed from window.location.hash
  // to window.location.search.  There was no hash in the URL.  So
  // .hash was returning an empty string.
  var hashFragment = window.location.search;
  if (hashFragment) {
    // split up the query string and store in an object
    var paramStrs = hashFragment.slice(1).split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < paramStrs.length; i++) {
      var paramStr = paramStrs[i].split("=");
      params[paramStr[0]] = unescape(paramStr[1]);
    }
  }
  return params;
}
```

in the realtime-client-utils.js fixed it